# Add multiples firewalls in symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.1, symfony-2.3

I have 2 bundles, the routing file `app/config/routing` is :

```
shop_admin:
    resource: "@ShopAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /admin

shop_desktop:
    resource: "@ShopDesktopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix:   /
```

Routing file for `ShopDesktopBundle` is :

```
login:
   pattern:   /login
   defaults:  { _controller: ShopDesktopBundle:User:login }

login_check:
   pattern:   /login_check
```

Routing file for `ShopAdminBundle` is :

```
admin_login:
   path:   /login
   defaults:  { _controller: ShopAdminBundle:Login:login }

admin_login_check:
   path:   /login_check
```

The `security.yml` :

```
firewalls:
    # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
    user_secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        form_login:
            login_path:  login
            check_path:  login_check
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
        logout:
            invalidate_session: true
            path:   shop_logout_user
            target: /
        anonymous: true
    admin_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/admin
        form_login:
            login_path: /admin/login
            check_path: /admin/login_check
            username_parameter: _username
            password_parameter: _password
        anonymous: true
```

The authentification work fine for the `ShopDesktopBundle` when I tried to authentificate on `ShopAdminBundle` I get the error : `Unable to find the controller for path "/admin/login_check". The route is wrongly configured.`
I think the problem is in my file `security.yml`. Can you help me please? Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As first thing change firewalls position. `user_secured_area` suits for all routes and it never hits `admin_secured_area`. I believe it will solve your issue.

```
firewalls:
    admin_secured_area:
       pattern: ^/admin
       ...
    user_secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        ...
```